# Ada: hiding implementation name in a (generic) package

Tags: package, private, ada

I want to put a wrapper or façade on **Ada.sequential_IO**.  This is a bit ugly but I'm trying to work with some auto-translated code.  So I've got:

```
with Ada.sequential_IO;

generic

     type element_type is private;

package queue_file is

     package implementation is new Ada.sequential_IO (element_type);

     subtype instance is implementation.file_type; 

     function eofQ (channel : instance) return Boolean renames implementation.end_of_file;
     procedure readQ (channel : in instance;  item : out element_type) renames implementation.read;
     -- etc.

end queue_file;
```

which is all very well but the name **queue_file.implementation** is visible.  I tried to move it into the private part and write **package implementation is private** but it's not having it.  So is there any way to hide the name ?

Comment: I don't think I'd call the subprograms `eofQ`, `readQ` etc. Why not just `eof`, `read`? (or even `End_Of_File`, `Read`? :) )

Comment: +1 for Simon : to make it explicit they are queue operations, use qualified names, queue_file.Read etc.

Comment: @Simon: it's just a consequence of what I'm trying to do, which is automatically to translate Pascal source code into Ada.  The Pascal names eof, read etc. are overloaded inasmuch as they can be applied to objects of type text and objects of type file of X.  I can give you the full and dirty details if you're interested, but it's very application-specific.

Comment: @Michael: no need for the details, sounds like you have good reasons! It's just that sometimes people _don't_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you're trying to do, at least not w/o breaking the visible dependence on `implementation` given by `subtype instance is implementation.file_type;`

Example:

```ada
private with Ada.Sequential_IO;

generic
    type element_type is private;
package queue_file is

    type instance is limited private;

    function eofQ (channel : instance) return Boolean;
    procedure readQ (channel : in instance;  item : out element_type);
    -- SUBPROGRAMS  FOR SEQUENTIAL_IO INTERFACE  --
    procedure Open
      (File : in out instance;
       Name : String;
       Write: Boolean;
       Form : String := "");

    procedure Read  (File : instance; Item : out Element_Type);
    procedure Write (File : instance; Item : Element_Type);
    -- etc.
private
    package implementation is new Ada.sequential_IO (element_type);

    type instance is new implementation.file_type;
end queue_file;
```

and

```ada
Pragma Ada_2012;
package body queue_file is

    function eofQ (channel : instance) return Boolean is
      ( implementation.end_of_file( implementation.File_Type(channel) ) );

    procedure readQ (channel : in instance;  item : out element_type) is
    use implementation;
    begin
    implementation.read( File_Type(Channel), item );
    end readQ;

    procedure Open
      (File : in out instance;
       Name : String;
       Write: Boolean;
       Form : String := "") is
    use implementation;
    begin
    Open(
         File => File_Type(File),
         Mode => (if Write then Out_File else In_File),
         Name => Name,
         Form => Form
        );
    end Open;

    -- left as an exercise      
    procedure Read  (File : instance; Item : out Element_Type) is null;
    procedure Write (File : instance; Item : Element_Type) is null;
    -- etc.
end queue_file;
```